# Avoid to inflate a layout when the content of current cursor is not needed

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a listview on a listactivity wich is populated by a sqlite database using a CursorAdapter activity.

Inside this CursorAdapter im using bindview and new view, it does work good. the problem is that i would like to inflate the view just when the content of the current cursor has the content i need.

public class TKMAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

```
private LayoutInflater inflator;
private int ciM, ciTM;


public TKMAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    ciM = c.getColumnIndex(TKMOpenHandler.MOD_MD);
    ciTM = c.getColumnIndex(TKMOpenHandler.MOD_TE);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) 
{
     //Code to populate the row.. text views ....and images...
    }
```

@Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

//Problem: according to the content of the current cursor i would like to be able to control if the view has to be inflated or not

```
     return inflator.inflate(R.layout.icon_text_text, null);

     }
```

Comment: why do you want to. inflate conditionally?

Comment: Because I want just specific data to be displayed on the list view

Comment: you are using a CursorAdapter, then change selection criteria in query() method